# Dirichlet eigenfunction cannot be extended to a continuous function on the closure

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions, laplacian

I need to show that there exist a bounded domain $ \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $, and a Dirichlet eigenfunction $u$ on $ \Omega$ such that u cannot be extended to a continuous function on $ \bar{\Omega}$ (closure).

Comment: @Ian I dont get it ,I get a continuous solution on the closed disk

Comment: How exactly do you define a Dirichlet eigenfunction, in what sense does it have zero values on the boundary?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the word "homogeneous" which is implicit in this context.

Comment: It have zero values on boundary : $u|_{d\Omega}=0$

Comment: @EliElizirov While that is the intuition, it is not very helpful in this context, because the equation lives on the inside of the domain. When you have continuity up to the boundary, it makes sense to say $u(z):=\lim_{x \to z} u(x)$ for $z$ on the boundary. But you don't in this situation. So you need something else. One common choice is called the *trace*, which is the extension of the restriction map to whatever Sobolev space you are working in.

Comment: I bet, that the definition is: $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$, $u \neq 0$ is an eigenfunction iff there is $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\int_\Omega \nabla u \, \nabla v + \lambda \, u \, v \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$ for all $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: In that case, your domain must be of very low regularity. Note that $u$ satisfies (in a weak sense) $-\Delta u = -\lambda u \in L^p(\Omega)$ for all $p \in [1,\infty)$. If the domain has a tiny bit of regularity (I think a Lipschitz domain is enough), then $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ for some $p > 2$ and this embeds into $C(\bar\Omega)$.

Comment: So you are probably looking for a domain with an exterior exponential cusp...